# Wordpress in subfolder /wp-admin redirect issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

A Wordpress website is installed in a subfolder, let's call it `my_site`

I need the website to load subfolder contents when the domain name is accessed (let's say it's `https://example.com`), and thus, I have set up my `.htaccess` file like so:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_site/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_site/index.php [L]
```

Now, in terms of content and the website overall - everything works correctly. The issue is with trying to login into the WP dashboard by going directly to `https://example.com/wp-admin`

Browser does load the standard WP login screen but upon entering my credentials, the same login form shows up - it's like I simply refreshed the page.

Both upon first going to the `https://example.com/wp-admin` URL and after trying to login, when I experience the "browser refresh-like" behavior, the URL string in browser is set automatically to:

`https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmy_site%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

Same URL decoded:

`https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https://example.com/my_site/wp-admin/&reauth=1`

So clearly the problem is that `my_site` is appended inside the `redirect_to` parameter, but I have no idea how to get rid of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S. The `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` variables are set in `wp-config.php` like so (to target both http and https):

```
$hostname = isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
$hostname .= '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
define( 'WP_HOME', $hostname );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', $hostname );
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey all you need to remove **(www.)?** from RewriteCond like so

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_site/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_site/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_site/index.php [L]
```

second, if you decode your URL via [URL Decoder](https://www.urldecoder.org/)

```
https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmy_site%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

you will notice **my_site** which is the root cause that does not allowing to redirect to wp dashboard because in htaccess you restrict to **example.com**.

Once you remove **my_site%2F** from URL and re-submit login form you will definitely redirect to dashboard.

Now all you need to config redirect URL to wp-admin such that it does not contain actual wordpress folder

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. You probabably have changed to https?
the solution is in the database.

[wordpress official site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble)

In some situations, your blog can be seen from inside your domain, but not outside. Following the instruction above about changing the wp-options MySQL table might still result in login failure.

In this event, double-check your wp-options table siteurl (WordPress address URL) and home (Blog Address URL) values to make sure they reference the same base externally available address; i.e., http://blog.yourdomain.com. The standard install may set them to your local (internal) host name, such as http://servername

Another issue may be if you are redirecting using .htaccess from a non-www url prefix to a www while you have the wp-options table siteurl (WordPress address URL) and home (Blog Address URL) set with non-www prefix. Consequently this would create an endless loop which you need to avoid. One way is to disable the .htaccess redirection temporarily by placing # before the line or eliminating the entries entirely and trying to Login again. Advanced users may want to adjust the wp-options table siteurl (WordPress address URL) and home (Blog Address URL) through the database. Notice that this issue can also occur if you are redirecting from www to non-www but have your wp-options table siteurl (WordPress address URL) and home (Blog Address URL) set with a www url prefix.